# Overriding arrangedObjects of NSTreeController

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstreecontroller

In my project an `NSTreeController` is bound to an `NSOutlineView`(cocoa binding). For some reason **I can't use `NSPredicate`** to filter data from Core Data. So I tried to override `arrangedObjects` of `NSTreeController`, but the overriding `arrangedObjects` **has not even been fired**. (I set a debugging breakpoint inside it.) The code compiles well and I've already changed the instance to my `CleanTreeController`. I only found [an unanswered question asked a decade ago](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/139412-mmalc-filteringarraycontroller-and-nstreecontroller-issues.html) in the mailing list.

```
// Subclass of NSTreeController
class CleanTreeController: NSTreeController {
    init() {
        // This gets called.
        super.init(content: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override var arrangedObjects: Any {
        let oldArranged = super.arrangedObjects

        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("childNodes")

        guard let oldChildren = (oldArranged as! NSObject)
                            .perform(selector).takeUnretainedValue() as? [NSTreeNode]
        else
        {
            return oldArranged
        }

        let children = oldChildren.filter { (treeNode) in
            //... do some filtering
        }

        return TreeNodeProxy(with: children)
    }
}

// Homemade NSTreeNodeProxy
class TreeNodeProxy : NSObject {

    fileprivate var rootNode : NSTreeNode

    init(with children : [NSTreeNode]) {
        self.rootNode = NSTreeNode()
        self.rootNode.mutableChildren.addObjects(from: children)
    }

    @objc(childNodes)
    var children: [NSTreeNode]? {
        return rootNode.children
    }

    @objc(descendantNodeAtIndexPath:)
    func descendant(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSTreeNode? {
        return rootNode.descendant(at: indexPath)
    }
}
```

I've found

> The value returned by NSTreeController's arrangedObjects method is
>   opaque. You should only observe this property to determine that a
>   change has occurred.

in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Articles/ControllerKey-ValueObservingCompliance.html). So how can `NSOutineView` consume `arrangedObjects` without reading it (directly)?

Comment: I tried this and `arrangedObjects` is called. Maybe it's easier to override the `content` setter?

Comment: Thanks. Just overrided the initializers for debugging, one of them gets called. This is weird.

Comment: I made an vanilla project for test, and it's the same: the `arrangedObjects` getter is not called when the app starts. (I bound things up programmatically, not in the xib. It shouldn't make any difference I guess.) However I just found that after removing the displayed objects, the arrangedObjects did get fired. I will look into it to see what made the difference.

Comment: I did bind everything in the xib in my test app and `arrangedObjects` is not called when the app starts. I assumed `arrangedObjects` wasn't called because there are no objects but it isn't called with objects either.

Answer (score 0):

Set `fetchPredicate` of the `NSTreeController` in the xib or in code.

Comment: Thanks. However fetchPredicate can't use computed property or transient attribute.